# nuxtjs calling vuex-mutation without name space

Tags: vuex, nuxt.js

How I can call mutation without name of it's module file?

store/index.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    counter: 0
})
```

store/todos.js

```
export const state = () => ({
    list: []
})

export const mutations = {
    add (state, text) {
        state.list.push({
            text: text,
            done: false
        })
    },
    remove (state, { todo }) {
        state.list.splice(state.list.indexOf(todo), 1)
    },
    toggle (state, todo) {
        todo.done = !todo.done
    }
}
```

in components I can call mutation like this:

```
this.$store.commit('todos/add', e.target.value)
```

but I don't want to write namespace. I want to use something like this command:

```
this.$store.commit('add', e.target.value)
```

Comment: "but i don't want to write namespace"... Why?

Comment: @Andrew1325 imagin in component  you use namespace like 'todoModule/add'' after some days you want to move your todoModule to new folder or you want to change the name of it .you have to change any where in your coponents then !

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by exporting [namespaced](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/modules.html#namespacing) variables

```
export const namespaced = false
```

But its not the best idea, better to have module name for better modularity

Comment: the best idea is having  module name dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Set namespaced variable to false  `namespaced: false` in export default function in a respective module. E.g

```
const state = () => ({
  counter: 0
})

const mutations = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter++
  }
}

const getters = {}

export default {
  namespaced: false,
  state,
  mutations,
  actions,
  getters
}
```

Or export it as separate variable `export const namespaced = false;`

```
export const namespaced = false;
export const state = () => ({
  counter: 0
})

export const mutations = {
  increment(state) {
    state.counter++
  }
}
```